# Microservice's High availability concern on cloud

Tags: cloud, microservices

I was reading about Microservices and everything makes sense to me but I have one little doubt.

On cloud, every component has a availability SLA (lets assume 99.9%). So, if we have a single component to do a job, our application SLA would be the same (approx.). But if we create multiple components to do one job, our application's SLA would be reduced because all the components can go down at different time. In microservices, one service can communicate to other services to complete a task. Now, any of the participant service can be down at different time, So our application availability will be lesser compared to monolithic service?

Comment: On the other hand, in case of monolith application, if one server goes down, everything goes down. And in case of microservices, if one services goes down, some part of the app still could be working. As Sumit mentioned, you need to care about most important parts of your app.

Comment: Pls check my comment in Sumit's answer.

Comment: Actually I'm talking a little bit about different thing. See, you have 99.95% availability assuming that the whole monolithic server will be alive. If only one server goes down, everything goes down. There is no reason to compare anything else — only cases when everything is completely broken and down do matter. And in case of monolithic architecture you have only one server, but in case of microservices — several. Chances that all servers in microservice architecture will go down are less than such chances for only one monolithic server. Are you following my idea?

Answer (score 0):

Not if all microservices are deployed in Highly Available(HA) configuration which is always the case for production environments.

Multiple Load Balanced instances of every microservice will ensure higher availability as well as higher load tolerance.

Comment: Event after deployed with HA, you can get 99.95% availability (for instance with Window Azure). Now if there are 5 microservices, every component will have 99.95% availability in isolation. Each service can be down 0.5% of time (at different instance), so in total 99.75% is the time when all components will be up and running. But if we had monolithic system, it would have 99.5% availability.

Comment: One more aspect which I think you missed. If you have 5 microservices, In production you will have 2 or more instances of a single microservice which makes it more than 10 instances in total. If one instance is 99.95% available, two instances of a microservice will virtually give you 100% availability.